# AWS - Can not create docker container on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am trying to create docker container on ec2 as follow

```
docker run -d --net mynetwork   -p 5000:5000  --name api_app 066898a67ca3
```

But it return following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "maps.pyx", line 91, in preshed.maps.PreshMap.set
       File "maps.pyx", line 133, in preshed.maps.map_set
       File "maps.pyx", line 258, in preshed.maps._resize
       File "cymem.pyx", line 74, in cymem.cymem.Pool.alloc


    MemoryError: Error assigning 67108864 bytes
    Exception ignored in: 'spacy.strings.StringStore._intern_utf8'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "maps.pyx", line 91, in preshed.maps.PreshMap.set
      File "maps.pyx", line 133, in preshed.maps.map_set
      File "maps.pyx", line 258, in preshed.maps._resize
      File "cymem.pyx", line 74, in cymem.cymem.Pool.alloc
    MemoryError: Error assigning 67108864 bytes
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

anybody can help to fix this issue on aws?

Answer (score 0):

You run out of memory. Try bigger EC2 instance or figure out what consumes all the memory on yours.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#MemoryError):

**exception MemoryError**
*Raised when an operation runs out of memory but the situation may still be rescued (by deleting some objects). The associated value is a string indicating what kind of (internal) operation ran out of memory. Note that because of the underlying memory management architecture (C’s malloc() function), the interpreter may not always be able to completely recover from this situation; it nevertheless raises an exception so that a stack traceback can be printed, in case a run-away program was the cause.*